# Sum with the von-Mangoldt function: $\sum_{1\leq x\leq n}\Lambda(x)^4$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $Λ$ be the [von-Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function). then
What is the estimate for the sum $\sum_{1\leq x\leq n}\Lambda(x)^{4}$?

Is this $\sum_{1\leq x\leq n}\Lambda(x)^{4}\sim n\log^3n$

also what can we say about this when $x\neq y$?
 $ \sum_{1\leq x, y\leq n}\Lambda(x)^{2}\cdot \Lambda(y)^{2}$?

Can any one help.
I'm trying this for a long time

Comment: Ummm.... what's $\Lambda$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think it's Von-Mangoldt function.

Comment: yes, Λ is the  Von-Mangoldt function.

Comment: I think you meant $\sim nlog^3n$?

Comment: yes i meant that, and edited in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)^4 = \sum_{n\le x} \Lambda(n)\log^3 n +O(x^{1/2}\log^4 x)$$ From there you can use the PNT and a partial summation, obtaining 
$$\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)^4 \sim \sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)\log^3 n\sim \sum_{n\le x}\log^3 n\sim x \log^3 x$$
The exact asymptotic is found from $$\sum_n\Lambda(n)  n^{-s}\log^3 n=\frac{d^3}{ds^3}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$$
Following the same method as in the PNT we obtain
$$\sum_{n\le x} \Lambda(n) \log^3 n = Res((\frac{d^3}{ds^3}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} )\frac{x^s}{s},1)+O(x\log^{-k} x) = \sum_{m=1}^4 c_m x \frac{\log^{m-1} x}{(m-1)!} +O(x\log^{-k} x)$$
Where $c_m$ is the coefficient of $(s-1)^{-m}$ in the Laurent expansion of $(\frac{d^3}{ds^3}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} )\frac1s$.

Under the RH the error term can be improved to $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: For $x\neq y$ Is $ \sum_{1\leq x, y\leq n}\Lambda(x)^{2}\cdot \Lambda(y)^{2}\sim n\mathrm{log}^2n$?

Comment: No. $\sum_{x\le n,y\le n} \Lambda(x)^2\Lambda(y)^2=(\sum_{x\le n} \Lambda(x)^2)^2\sim n^2\log^2 n$

Comment: okay, then, $ \sum_{1\leq x, y,w,t\leq n}\Lambda(x) \Lambda(y) \Lambda(w)\Lambda(t)\sim n^4 $ ? for$x\neq y\neq w\neq t$

Comment: .... $\sum_{x, y,w,t\leq n}\Lambda(x) \Lambda(y) \Lambda(w)\Lambda(t)=(\sum_{x\le n}\Lambda(x))^4$. Obviously the sum over $x,y,w,t$ distinct has the same asymptotic.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to get an asymptotic formula. We can use the Prime Number Theorem in the form $$\theta\left(x\right):=\sum_{p\leq x}\log\left(p\right)=x+O\left(\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}\right)$$ the trivial estimate $$\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda\left(n\right)^{4}=\sum_{p\leq x}\log^{4}\left(p\right)+O\left(\sqrt{x}\log^{3}\left(x\right)\right)$$ and the [Abel summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) $$\sum_{p\leq x}\log^{4}\left(p\right)=\theta\left(x\right)\log^{3}\left(x\right)-3\int_{2}^{x}\theta\left(t\right)\frac{\log^{2}\left(t\right)}{t}dt$$ to obtain $$\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda\left(n\right)^{4}=x\log^{3}\left(x\right)+O\left(x\log^{2}\left(x\right)\right).$$

Comment: @ marco, thanks for the nice answer